# How to compress online image within list view without binding actual size?

Tags: image, listview, xamarin.forms

How to Compress Online image that before binding with a list view in my xamarin forms application. actually online images are very high in size like 5MB,6MB,
My App getting crashed after seeing 9 or 10 images continuously.
any help pls????

Comment: Do you solve this problem? If not ,can show more info.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading), it has a method to resize to fit the view size

> DownsampleToViewSize (bool, default: false)
>
> If set to true image will resize to an image view size. Please note:
>   this could not work on some layouts (eg. absolute layouts without
>   RequestWidth/RequestWidthHeight specified, LayoutOptions.Fill in some
>   specific scenarios, etc). Algorithm for choosing size: First
>   View.Width/View.Height is checked, if it’s ⇐ 0 it falls back to:
>   View.RequestWidth/View.RequestHeight, if it’s ⇐ 0 it falls back to
>   using DownsampleWidth/DownsampleHeight properties. It’s not the best
>   option for image views that have no initial size defined. For that you
>   should use DownsampleWidth or DownsampleHeight properties and set your
>   downsample size manually.

An example:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
            Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

You can check their [official documentation](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#downsampling-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using the thumbnail for every image. Create a thumbnail while saving the image. When you load the images in the listview load thumbnail and in detail view open the actual Image. This is the correct way to handle this scenario.

If you are using Azure Blob storage to store the image then you can write a function which will trigger when you upload an image it will create a thumbnail of an Image.